# can I use a timer script such as a chrontab in an Apache environment?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, apache

I am wondering if I can institute a chronTab that will run a php script from within an Apache web server (on Unix based systems). My interest is in incorporating it with the javascript server side program Node.

This would be to be able to 'ping' a browser to see if it is still "in the ball park" so far as when to end sessions,
etc. The chronTab would be used to monitor some kind of script written file that would contain a record of ajax sent
messages telling the server that is still interested in some content. The chrontab would determine if there was a
sufficient amount of time since the last ajax request to close a session.

Possibly, if not probably the chrontag script would be written in php a command line interface script (or other shell or
script type?)

These are details that I have been thinking about but don't know enough about to use.

Thank you for time and attention

Comment: Can you use [cpanel](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs) to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the regular system cron, and create a job that does a wget at the URL where your script resides? So you would add a job like this in your crontab:

`*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -t 1 http://example.com/cgi-bin/my_cron_script.php`

It will execute every 5 minutes and call the my_cron_script.php on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean crontab? 
If so, and if you have shell access to the box:

> crontab -e

and add entry for the php script you want to run:

0 */4 * * * /path/to/php /full/path/to/script_to_run.php

NOTE: Use full paths to both php and your script and your php might be installed in a different directory.  Use 'which php' to get the full path.